# How to get a database object based on an OBJECT_ID?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server 2008, is there a way to access an object based on the `OBJECT_ID`?

[Edit] The example described below was solved using Andrew's suggestion in the comment, but I'm still curious about the general case. Can an object itself be retrieved using `OBJECT_ID`, or can it only be accessed indirectly by using the object name via `sp_executesql`?

My specific case is a stored procedure that uses several temporary tables. At the end of the procedure I want to dump the data from the temporary tables into actual tables for analysis (only if a debug switch is enabled).

The code for dumping the data is similar to this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MyTempTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID('Debug_MyTempTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE Debug_MyTempTable
    SELECT * INTO Debug_MyTempTable FROM #MyTempTable
END
```

This code block is repeated for each temporary table, so I would prefer to put it in a procedure and call it with a table name:

```
EXEC [dbo].[CreateDebugTable]
    @tableName = 'MyTempTable'
```

I imagine the procedure would look something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateDebugTable]
    @tableName VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#' + @tableName, 'U') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
      IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Debug_' + @tableName, 'U') IS NOT NULL
          DROP TABLE <Debug_TempTable>
      SELECT * INTO <Debug_TempTable> FROM <#TempTable>
    END
END
```

The procedure depends on being able to translate the `OBJECT_ID` of `DebugTempTable` and `#TempTable` into the actual tables (shown with <> in the code above). Is this possible?

[Edit]
This is the altered procedure using `sp_executesql` instead of explicit tables.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateDebugTable]
    @tableName VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @tmpTable VARCHAR(50) = '#' + @tableName
    DECLARE @dboTable VARCHAR(50) = 'Debug_' + @tableName
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(100)

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..' + @tmpTable, 'U') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.' + @dboTable, 'U') IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            SET @sql = 'DROP TABLE ' + @dboTable
            EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
        END

        SET @sql = 'SELECT * INTO ' + @dboTable + ' FROM ' + @tmpTable
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
    END
END
```

Comment: Couldn't you just sp_executesql the statement instead and not worry about converting it back? You seem to have the names as strings, so generate a stmt and execute it- or am I missing part of the problem?

Comment: @Andrew, yes you're right I could do that. I missed the obvious :) Thanks

Comment: Np, question probs has limited value to keep so I would recommend you just delete it.

Comment: You can use OBJECT_NAME (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186301(v=SQL.105).aspx).  But as @Andrew noted, this would have to but put into a string and executed anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `object_id` is just used as a key in the various metadata views. There is no `TSQL` syntax to `SELECT` from (or otherwise manipulate) objects based on their `object_id`.

If you have an `object_id` then in general you could use

```
SELECT QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@object_id[,database_id])) + 
       '.' + 
       QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(@object_id[,database_id]) )
```

To get the 2 part name of the object but for `#temp` tables this returns the long internal name rather than the short one that you can actually use in queries.